# XSL Choose condition hyperlink for entire table row

Tags: xslt, hyperlink

I would like to add a hyperlink to a table row that naviagates to one of two web pages depending on if a value is returned for one of the XML results.  I'm not sure if I have a syntax issue or if this logic is not possible.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Rowset/Row">
  <tr>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">  
      <xsl:choose>   
        <xsl:when test="ID_PRODU_ORDER!=''">
          <xsl:value-of select="/XMII/CM/Molex/ProductionExecution/OrderPostConfirmationBox.irpt">
        </xsl:when>  
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="/XMII/CM/Molex/ProductionExecution/MachineAssignNewOrderMobile.irpt">
        </xsl:otherwise>   
      </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:attribute> 

    <td align="left">  
      <xsl:attribute name="id">  
      </xsl:attribute> 
      <xsl:value-of select="DS_MACHI" />
    </td> 

    <td align="left">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID_PRODU_ORDER" />
    </td>

    <td align="left" >
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="NR_DAY_REMAI" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Well, for one, if your link is the "/XMII/CM/Molex/ProductionExecution/(...).irpt" value, then you should either put single quotes around it in the select or use xsl:text. Also, are you trying to put a href on a tr?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make each table row an intedendant hyperlink based on the condition logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean check to determine the string existence:

```
<xsl:variable name="order" select="boolean(ID_PRODU_ORDER)"/>
```

Use a pair of processing instructions in a separate file such as `test.xml` to store the true and false URLs:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <?_true /XMII/CM/Molex/ProductionExecution/OrderPostConfirmationBox.irpt?>
  <?_false /XMII/CM/Molex/ProductionExecution/MachineAssignNewOrderMobile.irpt?>
</root>
```

Reference the file using the document function:

```
<xsl:variable name="href" select="document('test.xml')//processing-instruction(concat('_', $order) )"/>

<tr>
  <a href="{$href}">
    <td id="{DS_MACHI}"></td>
    <td id="{ID_PRODU_ORDER}"></td>
    <td id="{NR_DAY_REMAI}"></td>
  </a>
</tr>
```